# Geddy - Node not restarting after saving any files

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, geddy

Not sure why this all of a sudden is broken, but when running Geddy, anytime I make a change, say in the controller, view, model. It isn't recognized and geddy does not restart.

Currently running ver:

Node: v0.10.20 via homebrew on Mac 10.8
Geddy: 0.10.3 via npm install -g geddy

Update:

Had to install geddy via: sudo npm install -g geddy

Seems to be restarting anytime files are saved now.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues/194), Geddy needs to be installed locally (without the `-g` flag) in order for it to correctly trigger a restart when files in the project are changed.

Comment: Yeah, when I installed geddy, it was with the -g, npm install -g geddy

Comment: No, let me give that a shot

Comment: Yeah, no dice. I just installed nvm, thought I'd try running node 0.8, but still, no dice...

Comment: Got it working. I did the following, but is their any down side to this?  sudo npm install -g geddy

Comment: No, there's no downside to globally installing with `sudo`.  In fact, that's the proper way to do it.